# Component not rendered after async handler first yield

Tags: blazor-webassembly

Here is the basic blazor counter but the onclick handler is async.

```html
@page "/counter"

<PageTitle>Counter</PageTitle>

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p role="status">Current count: @currentCount</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCountAsync">Click me</button>

@code {
    private int currentCount = 0;

    private async Task IncrementCountAsync()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
        {
            currentCount++;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

I would like the counter to be incremented by one every second on a button click. But currently it first increments it by one, and then by 9 10 seconds later.

It seems like blazor does something like

```cs
var task = IncrementCountAsync();
Render();
await task;
Render();
```

How can I solve that issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding StateHasChanged after you increment the count

```
private async Task IncrementCountAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i += 1)
    {
        currentCount++;
        StateHasChanged();
        await Task.Delay(1000);
    }
}
```

Calling that: 'Notifies the component that its state has changed. When applicable, this will cause the component to be re-rendered'